# Setting up VM in openshift to configure SELENIUM GRID

Tags: selenium, virtual-machine, openshift, selenium-grid

I am trying to setup Selenium GRID in openshift. In the process I am thinking to setup a Virtual machine and start node and hub inside it. 
Kindly help me with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up GRID is quite simple really. You just need to make sure you have JDK installed and follow the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)

Comment: its about setting it up on openshift - RHEL to be specific - do you have steps for doing it on openshift?